# Why can't Gradle resolve "com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0" in my spring boot app

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, gradle

For some reason I cannot get 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0' to work with my project. The gradle build says cannot resolve but is still successful somehow. How do I get this to resolve so it will build properly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Realized i was in offline mode. My Bad

[image]